# How implement the Has Many Through Association on Controllers and methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-many-through, simple-form-for

in my app I'm creating the categories in admin(so the admins creates, updates and destroys the categories name) and then when the users will create the posts they will select( or I'm thinking for switch with checkbox) a category for the posts.

I decide to do this implementation with a has many through for posts and categories. But I' having doubts for implements:

1. the post_params;
2. the methods for add the categories and then destroy the categories
3. and the parts for create, update and destroy the posts.

How can I implement this? It's a better way do different? So if someone help me with this I will appreciate.

Post.rb

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :categorizations
       has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
    ...
      def add_category(category)
        categorizations.create(category_id: category.id)
      end

      def remove_category(category)
        categorizations.find_by(category_id: category.id).destroy
      end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations

  validates :name,
                  presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 30 },
                  uniqueness: true
end
```

categorization.rb

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category

  validates :post_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

controllers/admin/PostsController

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.author = current_user
    @post.categories << params[:category_id]

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post has been created."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Post has not been created."
      render "new"
    end
  end



  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Post has been deleted."
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,
                                 :subtitle,
                                 :content,
                                 :attachment,
                                 :attachment_cache,
                                 :remote_attachment_url,
                                 :categorizations_attributes => [:id,
                                                                 :post_id,
                                                                 :category_id,
                                                                 :_destroy,
                                                                 :categories_attributes => [:id,
                                                                                            :name]
                                                                ]
                                 )
  end
end
```

controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @posts = policy_scope(Post)
  end

  def show
    authorize @post, :show?
  end

  def edit
    authorize @post, :update?
  end

  def update
    authorize @post, :update?
    if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Post has been updated."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Post has not been updated."
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:alert] = "The post you were looking for could not be found."
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :content, :attachment, :attachment_cache, :remove_attachment, :remote_attachment_url, :category_id)
  end
end
```

posts/_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, @post], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
   = select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select ad Category")
```

routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin do
    root 'application#index'

    resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :categories

    resources :users do
      member do
        patch :archive
      end
    end
  end

  devise_for :users

  root "posts#index"

  resources :posts, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form

```
= select_tag(:category_ids, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select ad Category", multiple: true)
```

In your controller

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :content, :attachment, :attachment_cache, :remove_attachment, :remote_attachment_url, :category_ids)
```

Also need to give some advise, in your posts_controller.rb
 remove below line

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

Insterad of this write it in application_controller.rb , so it will work for whole application.

Comment: Hello Vishal, thank's for reply.
I try this but the code but isn't complete. I think is the part for add the categories on categorizations. I was trying do this: `@post.categories << params[:category_id]`, but isn't work.

But I do a method on `Post.rb` called `add_category`. I think it's something in that way, but I'm not totally confident. Can you help me solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

What I do for fix was put on the PostsController this:

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  before_action :set_categories, only: [:new, :create]
   .
   .
   .
  private

  def set_categories
    @categories = Category.all.select(:id, :name)
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,
                                 :subtitle,
                                 :content,
                                 :attachment,
                                 :attachment_cache,
                                 :remote_attachment_url,
                                 category_ids:[]
                                 )
  end
```

And on the form I changed for use checkboxes and with that I can select and add more categories for a Post:

```
   = f.association :categories, label: "Select the Categories", as: :check_boxes , collection: @categories.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_hidden: false
```

Add on the class Post and Category a `dependent: :destroy` for destroy the joins properly.

```
has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
```

And was necessary delete the validation for post_id on categorization so I just comment because when was uncommented when I try to create a Post it wasn't possible, So I do this:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category

  #validates :post_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

And work's!

Comment: I don't think you need to remove any associations. you can do in this way `<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:categories_ids, @categories, :id, :name) do |category| %>
  <%= category.label { category.check_box } %>
<% end %>`  OR `<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <label>
      <%= check_box_tag "post[categories_ids][]", category.id, f.object.categories.include?(category) %>
      <%= category.name %>
   </label>
<% end %>`

Comment: I think select box is good solution over checkbox because when your categories exceed more than 100 it will not look good in ui part as checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for show me your perspective. But I don't think it will have so much categories in the maximum 10 I think. But if will be the case I will change. But one question, in a case if I change for select. How I will select more then one categories with select?
Thank's for the help and reply Vishal!

Comment: You can use select2 jquery plugin https://select2.org/ , which is very helpful, with select2 you can pass attributes multipe: true, so you can select multiple options in select box.

Comment: nice plugin Vishal. I will try do something with this( this will be nice for tags too) and your checkboxes example. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome , you can also upvote my answer if it is worked for you !!

Comment: Sorry Vishal, I don't upvote because I'm doing other things. And I don't programming right now. I need to do some things for me on the street and then later I will try do this things. And I know if it's work's I will upvote!

Comment: I try to do this type of checkboxes and the result is similar of the mine. The only thing that I don't liked was the style of the checkboxes, they are in horizontal. And I try to do in vertical mode, but with a while I desist.
And the similar problem of validates the post_id on categorizations persists with this checkboxes. 

Because the categorizations it will be created when the post was saved. I try to put this validation when was for update and work's of course, but when I try to create a new Post. It's getting this error of validation. I can get created just when I commit this line.

Comment: My code for this with slim-rails gem was:
`= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, @categories, :id, :name) do |category|
    .form-horizontal.collection_check_box
      = category.check_box
      = category.label`

Comment: And before that all this tries I do the sample of the Rails Casts with David Heinemeier the episode  #17 HABTM Checkboxes (revised).
`= hidden_field_tag "post[category_ids][]", nil 
  - Category.all.each do |category|
     = check_box_tag "post[category_ids][]", category.id, @post.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category)
     = label_tag dom_id(category)
     = category.name
     br`
But I liked more the first solution that I solved here before. Anyway thank you Vishal for the help!